# Why is there no response data and why are variables unresolved in my AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, variables

What is wrong here? I've scoured StackOverflow, read Angular and PHP manuals, and attempted to use some code that other people used, and still nothing has solved the problem.

I cannot figure out why there is no response data and why the `{{user.variable_names}}` are unresolved, nothing is showing up when I run the code. I have debugged as much as possible, but still not luck.

MarketController.js

```
var OrchidApp = angular.module('OrchidApp', ['ui.router', 'ngCookies']);

OrchidApp.controller('MarketController', function ($http, $scope) {
$http.get('market.php')
   .then(function (response) {
       $scope.users = response;
   });
});
```

Market.php

```
<?php

include 'dbConfig.php';

$sel = mysqli_query($con,"select * from Chef");
if (!$sel) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}
$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sel)) {
    $point = array("fullname"=>$row['fullname'],"city"=>$row['city'],"state"=>$row['state'],"zip_code"=>$row['zip_code'],"rating"=>$row['rating']);
    array_push($data, $point);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="OrchidApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Orchid</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body class="container">

<div>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users" data-ng-controller="MarketController">
            <td>{{user.fullname}}</td>
            <td>{{user.city}}</td>
            <td>{{user.state}}</td>
            <td>{{user.zip_code}}</td>
            <td>{{user.rating}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- Libraries -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<!-- App Scripts -->
<script src="../server.js"></script>
<script src="../marketControllers.js"></script>
<script src="../dbHelpers/market.php"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

[image: What shows up when I run the app.]

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If this is your plain code, you are missing, at least, the angular bootstrap. In other words you need to initialize your angular app by automatic or manual process.
If you want automatic initialization, just put something like this in your html tag:

```
<html ng-app="optionalModuleName" ng-strict-di>
```

Or if you want to do it manual, you can do this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MarketController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    ...
  }]);

angular.element(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

Also, you should check if the response exists or not so you don't get unexpected results

Check here for more info about bootstrap angular: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Your response is the response.object, if you want to get the body, you have to use the data-Property like this:

```
var OrchidApp = angular.module('OrchidApp', ['ui.router', 'ngCookies']);

OrchidApp.controller('MarketController', function ($http, $scope) {
$http.get('market.php')
   .then(function (response) {
       $scope.users = response.data;
   });
});
```